# Why does start-all.sh from root cause "failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master: JAVA_HOME is not set"?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cloudera

I am trying to execute a Spark application built through Scala IDE through my standalone Spark service running on cloudera quickstart VM 5.3.0.

My cloudera account JAVA_HOME is /usr/java/default

However, I am facing the below error message while executing the start-all.sh command from `cloudera` user as below:

```
[cloudera@localhost sbin]$ pwd
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/sbin
[cloudera@localhost sbin]$ ./start-all.sh
chown: changing ownership of `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/sbin/../logs': Operation not permitted
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/sbin/../logs/spark-cloudera-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-localhost.localdomain.out
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/sbin/spark-daemon.sh: line 151: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/sbin/../logs/spark-cloudera-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-localhost.localdomain.out: Permission denied
failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master:
tail: cannot open `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/sbin/../logs/spark-cloudera-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-localhost.localdomain.out' for reading: No such file or directory
full log in /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/sbin/../logs/spark-cloudera-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-localhost.localdomain.out
cloudera@localhost's password: 
localhost: chown: changing ownership of `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/logs': Operation not permitted
localhost: starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/logs/spark-cloudera-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-localhost.localdomain.out
localhost: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/sbin/spark-daemon.sh: line 151: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/logs/spark-cloudera-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-localhost.localdomain.out: Permission denied
localhost: failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker:
localhost: tail: cannot open `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/logs/spark-cloudera-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-localhost.localdomain.out' for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: full log in /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/logs/spark-cloudera-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-localhost.localdomain.out
```

I had added `export CMF_AGENT_JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default` in `/etc/default/cloudera-scm-agent` and run `sudo service cloudera-scm-agent restart`. See [How to set CMF_AGENT_JAVA_HOME](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/4.7.0/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_java_home_location.html)

I had also added `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default` in `locate_java_home` function definition in file `/usr/share/cmf/bin/cmf-server` and restarted the cluster and standalone Spark service

But the below error is repeating while starting spark service from `root` user

```
[root@localhost spark]# sbin/start-all.sh
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/sbin/../logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-localhost.localdomain.out
failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master:
  JAVA_HOME is not set
full log in /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.0-1.cdh5.3.0.p0.30/lib/spark/sbin/../logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-localhost.localdomain.out
root@localhost's password: 
localhost: Connection closed by UNKNOWN
```

Can anybody suggest how to set JAVA_HOME so as to start Spark standalone service on cloudera manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution had been quite easy and straightforward. Just added `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default` in `/root/.bashrc` and it successfully started the spark services from `root` user without the `JAVA_HOME is not set` error. Hope it helps somebody facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

set JAVA_HOME variable in `~/.bashrc` as follows

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

write this line in the file (address of your installed JDK)

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
```

Then command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```