# Running Spark on Linux : $JAVA_HOME not set error

Tags: linux, apache-spark, java-home, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to configure `spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7`  on `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`. I have set

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/marc/jdk1.8.0_101
export SCALA_HOME=/home/marc/scala-2.11.8
export SPARK_HOME=/home/marc/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

at the end of `.bashrc` and also included in the `start-all.sh` file from spark/sbin folder

when I type `echo $JAVA_HOME` it gives me the correct path as `/home/marc/jdk1.8.0_101`

But when I call  `sbin/start-all.sh`

It gives me the following error

> localhost: failed to launch
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker: localhost:   JAVA_HOME is not
>   set

I tried to follow similar topics, but I couldn't find a solution to the problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you running just a single node worker?

Comment: And what user account did you add those variables for?

Comment: There is only one user account on the system which belongs to me, and yes I am running a single node worker

Comment: You are forgetting the `root` user, probably. Similar question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955635/why-does-start-all-sh-from-root-cause-failed-to-launch-org-apache-spark-deploy

Comment: @cricket_007 I added the code as instructed in the link you showed me but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Just curious - Why did you install Java to your home folder?

Comment: well I was just following a tutorial of setting up apache zeppelin with spark. And for spark setup scala and java were required.

Comment: Right, I understand that, but you are on Ubuntu, so should install Java from `apt-get`, and I believe that sets `JAVA_HOME` without you needing to mess with it.

Comment: hmm yes but my internet speed was quite low and I am running linux in a virtual box and had jdk previously downloaded on my windows instance hence I preferred to get it from there

Comment: The windows Java binaries can't be used a linux installation... Unless, you mean you had the Linux binary package downloaded? If that is the case, then you can still install with `dkpg -i jdk.deb`, or something like that

Comment: yes I had the linux binary package downloaded I will try to install it properly to see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to modify the file named 'spark-config.sh' in the 'sbin'.
Add your JAVA_HOME in this file, then everything will be OK.

Answer (score 17):

Try installing Java at your computer:

First, check if it is there:

```
java -version
```

If not installed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: this does not fix the issue.

Comment: It did fix for me, as well as for loads of other people, it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to config JAVA_HOME in the spark_env.sh file.